# Probability problem with a given probability density function

Tags: probability-distributions, problem-solving

I am strangely stuck on how to do this probability problem on certain sections upon going through some past papers:

> [image]

**part a)**

For this part, do I compute two integrals from $[1,2]$ using $f(x)=3a$ and $[2,3]$ using $f(x)=a(x-5)(1-x)?$

I am kind of stuck on **c)**, if they gave me one pdf $f(x)$ I think I know how to do this, but when they give me a pdf $f(x)$broken down with respect to a given domain, I am confused on how to find the mean and median. Can anyone show me how to do this, or give me some hints? I would appreciate it.

Comment: You got the right idea for a) but note it says from $1$ to $3$ not from $0$ to $3$ as you describe in your approach. For c) remember that we must have the integral from $0$ to $b$ be equal to $1$. Knowing this, you can solve for the value of $a$ in terms of $b$. (And yes the integral will be broken apart again to solve)

Comment: You'll have the sum of two integrals, each with limits corresponding to each part of the density domain.

Comment: Also, perhaps you're supposed to use $b=5$ for part c) as well but it isn't quite clear to me

Comment: Yes thank you for the reply, the only part I am stuck with is the median part now. How would I compute the median in this particular case?

Comment: The median is the value $m$ such that $$\int_{0}^m f(x) \, dx = 0.5$$

Comment: But there isn’t only one function so how would I compute $m$ for the two functions split up?

Answer (score 1):

For part c, you are given that the value of $b$ is 5. Using this information, and the fact that $\int_{x=0}^{5}{f(x) dx} = 1$, you can compute the value of $a$. This would define $f(x)$ completely.

The median $m$ is defined as the value in the domain of the random variable $X$ such that $Pr(X\leq m) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $Pr(X\geq m) = \frac{1}{2}$. As pointed out by @WaveX in the comments, you simply need to compute $m$ such that $\int_{0}^{m} f(x) = \frac{1}{2}$.

As for the mean, the mean of a probability distribution is simply the expected value of that variable.

Hope this clears up your question.